# Run cron job every x minutes plus offset seconds

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler

I understand this cron expression means run every 10 minutes.

```
0 */10 * ? * *
```

However, I've got the application that will run a Quartz job that's deployed to many devices so I want to slightly offset the cron expression by `x` seconds i.e. every 10 minutes and `x` seconds, where `x` will very for each device.

How can I generate the cron expression dynamically based on the `x` seconds?

Comment: Create a random value between 0-59 and replace the first 0 with that value.